# What i cannot connect to mysql from my jsp?

Tags: java

i cannot connect to database from my jsp. Code is below

```
  <% 
        try {
        /* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine name, 
        port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost and 
        database name is usermaster. */ 
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"; 

        // declare a connection by using Connection interface 
        Connection connection = null; 

        // Load JBBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 

        /* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes parameters of 
        string type connection url, user name and password to connect to database. */ 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "pass");

        // check weather connection is established or not by isClosed() method 
        if(!connection.isClosed())
        %>
        <font size="+3" color="green"></b>
        <% 
        out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
        connection.close();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
        %>
        </font>
        <font size="+3" color="red"></b>
        <%
        out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
        }
        %>
```

I connected to database and event search queries what might be the problem? I simply c/p from a source and put my jsp. Password and username is true.

Comment: What is the exception its throwing?

Comment: it just print 'Unable to connect to database.'

Comment: exception is that java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: This exception mostly comes when you misplace or did not added your jar file to your project. Make sure you have correct jar and added to buidpath and I will also suggest to check for connection by `if(connection!=null)`

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL driver jar file must be placed in the WEB-INF/lib directory of your deployed webapp.

Also note that:

- JSPs shouldn't access the database. This should be done in a service called by a servlet.
- Connections should always be closed in a finally block. Not doing it will leave connections open if you have any exception, and will quickly bring the system to its knees
- A webapp should use a connection pool. Read your app server or web container documentation for how to setup aconnection pool.

Answer (score 0):

Add the exceptions message to your self created error output:

out.println("Unable to connect to database: "+ex.getMessage());